# cannot set defaultValye in rc-time-picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timepicker

Hey guys i am using npm package called rc-time-picker

[see npm library here] https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-time-picker

so on editing my post what i want is i am getting a 'time' field from my database that was set by this rc-time-picker package at the time of adding the form

now as soons as i click on edit form i want to display this 'time' field which i get back from my db as defaultValue in rc-time-picker inputbox

I tried this but it doesnt work

data stored in mongodb is like

```
time:"2:02 pm"
```

After getting my data i did

```
this.setstate({time:res.time}) 

                 <TimePicker
                 showSecond={false}
                 defaultValue={this.state.time}
                 className="xxx"
                 onChange={this.onChange}
                 format={format}
                 use12Hours
                 inputReadOnly
                 />
onChange = (value) => {
console.log(value.format(format));
this.setState({ startTimeForLaterSchedule: 
value.format(format),scheduleTimePickerErrorMessage:false });
```

};

but nothing shows up as defaultValue in input box (though i am able to change the time by selecting it but i need to initially show the time)

Answer (score 1):

Hı ,
according to documentation , defaultValue's type is moment. did you try your time convert to moment ?

try this :

```
const now = moment().hour(0).minute(0);

  <TimePicker
    showSecond={false}
    defaultValue={now}
    className="xxx"
    onChange={onChange}
    format={format}
    use12Hours
    inputReadOnly
  />
```